# SMTP EOFError when Checking for Email Existence

Tags: ruby, smtp

I've written a simple script to test for the existence of an email address by initiating an SMTP communication without ever sending a message. For most domains, this works. But for some, like the one show below, I get an EOF error. I don't have this issue when using telnet to communicate with the SMTP server directly.

```
require 'net/smtp'

mx_server = 'mx1.optonline.net' # Example of a problematic mail host
Net::SMTP.start mx_server, 25 do |smtp|
  smtp.helo 'mydomain.com'
  smtp.mailfrom 'user@mydomain.com' # Triggers an EOF error
  smtp.rcptto 'target@optonline.net'  # Typically triggers an error if the address doesn't exist
end
```